# iOS inApp Purchase Validation

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase

Another inApp question concerning Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/

First of all he uses

```
    NSString *localIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Isn't it forbidden to work with UUIDs now?

Second:
When exactly does the user get charged money? Thinking about this scenario:
User Buys inApp X --> All goes well and completeTransaction: gets called --> Now trying to validate the receipt --> Internet connection breaks up --> Validation failed --> Content does not get unlocked

Did the user get charged but won't receive what he paid for? Will it automatically retry as soon as the internet is back up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It seems that you are [confusing a UUID with the UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461079/how-unique-are-the-ids-generated-with-cfuuid-in-ios/16461426#16461426).
2. The previous tutorial ([Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)), said this about `finishTransaction`:

> Note: It is very important to call finishTransaction, or StoreKit will
>   not know you’ve finished processing it, and will continue delivering
>   the transaction to your app each time it launches!

In the present tutorial, `finishTransaction` is called **after** the validation. This ensures that you'll be notified again if you don't finish the validation:

Comment: 1) Thanks!
2) actually it's calling finishTransaction in case of failure (look at validateReceiptForTransaction)
That's what confuses me. EDIT: It's also called in completeTransaction: itself. So it's kind of called anyway.