# How to map a CFUUID to a known UDID for beta testing purposes?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, udid

We would like to use CFUUIDs for beta testing purposes and for this it would be great if there is a possibility to map a generated CFUUID to a known(!) UDID?

Following workflow:
1) The user X takes part in the beta testing phase and communicates its UDID to us.
2) The provisioning profile is created containing the given UDID and we give X the provisioning profile and the app (archived .ipa file).
3) While testing X sends data to our server signed with the CFUUID generated in the app.
4) Finally, we would like to verify data by mapping CFUUIDs to already communicated and known(!) UDIDs, but HOW?

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 7 this is no longer possible, all unique identifiers of device are inaccessible for developers.

You can therefore no longer request the device UDID, mac address or other unique identifiers.

CFUUID are not base on UDID, at least not in a way that you can extrapolate a UDID from it.
Just have a look at these UUID, which are from the same device:

- `94808D35-D1C5-47FB-B7A5-D1F554896240`
- `E1EFC7B7-5C9E-4285-8A2C-19D5FE80DF27`
- `1E5AD874-4D1E-40D8-8B33-A59AE60FB2B3`

Als you can see only the `*********-****-4***-y****-**********` is the same,and `y` is is one of 8, 9, A, or B.
This should indicate that [Version 4 (random)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) is used.

Even if they would use the UDID to generate the UUID it will be like a hash (MD4, SHA) you can't get the original back. Only something that would generate the same hash, which could be the original.

Just check the source of [CFUUID](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-299/Base.subproj/CFUUID.c) you will see that **NO** UDID is used.

Comment: Hi. That is clear. We are not interested in requesting UDID. We have them already! We need a mapping operation between CFUUIDs and UDIDs.

Comment: Well then just print the CFUUID somewhere in the app and let the tester mail you that number to you, so you are able to map CFUUID to the UDID on your server.

Comment: That is exactly what we want to avoid. It would be great if we would not have to bother the user again. He already gave us his UDID. The CFUUID uses UDID for generation. Hence, there should be a way to do it…at least, we hope so. :-)

Comment: No CFUUID does not use UDID, there is just no way for you as a developer to get the UDID anymore.

Comment: It does…at least part of it or any other unique part of the device itself. That's the reason why CFUUID is unique. Check this for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461079/how-unique-are-the-ids-generated-with-cfuuid-in-ios

Comment: Nowhere is that documented, and I can say that it is not true, here are some UUID I've create on one device: `94808D35-D1C5-47FB-B7A5-D1F554896240`, `E1EFC7B7-5C9E-4285-8A2C-19D5FE80DF27`, `1E5AD874-4D1E-40D8-8B33-A59AE60FB2B3`. As you can see that are totally unique. There is no correlation between the UUID and the UDID.

Comment: :-) You cannot see it like that. It could be just a part of it and then combined with the time stamp and then…a few more adds and muls, etc. No need to discuss it any further…still hope that anyone has an idea.

Comment: Guess you are just not willing to except that it is not possible, unless you can have the source of CFUUID and the exact timestamp used (highly unlikely) you might be able to get the original data back. see the source: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-299/Base.subproj/CFUUID.c No UDID is used!

Comment: @grafd - Apple has taken extra steps in iOS7 to prevent developers to learn a device's UDID, so unless you believe that these developers at Apple are complete idiots you should accept the truth - that they succeeded.

Comment: @grafd did you manage to have a look at the source and do in the impossible yet?